# Why is it called 'wchar_t' and not simply 'wchar'?

Tags: c++, c, terminology

I've often wondered why C++ went with the name `wchar_t` instead of simply `wchar`, and I've never been able to find an answer. Search engines are no help because they think I'm asking about Windows' `WCHAR` type. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to see when the ANSI standard was written and when MS added the wchar to their compiler.  It may be that wchar_t is to differentiate between that and wchar that MS supports.  I may be wrong so I will do this as a comment, so I don't get downvoted. :)

Comment: I have a feeling the standard committees don't care as much about what MS does as MS would like to believe ;)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's a legacy from C, where `wchar_t` is a `typedef`, and `typedef`s have that suffix in the C Standard Library.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't realized it was originally part of C.

Comment: But it happened when C++ was coming up and new ISO standards were hammered out.

Comment: I know one of C++'s design goals was to remain as compatible with standard C as possible. I can understand their decision, though I can't say I agree with that particular motivation.

Comment: If I remember corrctly it was a two-way street, C imported function-prototypes from C++

Answer (score 12):

The C standard library has used the `_t` suffix for many of the types that are defined in the library (as opposed to the types that are baked into C itself as keywords).

For example, there's `time_t`, `wchar_t`, `uint32_t`, `size_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, `div_t`, etc.

Of interest (to me anyway) is that the C standard doesn't reserve names of that form for itself. The C standard does indicate that names that start with "`str`", "`mem`", and a few other prefixes might be added to the standard in the future, but it doesn't do the same with names that end in "`_t`" - except that names that start with "`int`" or "`uint`" and end with "`_t`" might be added to `<stdint.h>` in the future.  However, POSIX does reserve all names that end in "`_t`".

Answer (score 5):

I think this was a 'phase' in the  growing up of C and C++. The need for some new types was felt but adding new keywords is always disputed. Some code was already using `wchar`, far less code would have used `wchar_t`. Note that `size_t` and `diff_t` are of the same era.